# Global appIncluder function to include sub-applications dynamically

Tags: python, pyramid

I have implemented a global `appIncluder` function which is imported as includeme with the **init**.py of the package to be included.

`includeme` (`ApplicationIncluder`) receives the config object, so it is then easy to use config.package and its variables/methods/classes (present in the same **init**.py and submodules.

I would really appreciate getting some feedback on this and see what can be improved.

project: 'foo'

Apps to be deployed in foo.foo.apps directory.

Structure:

> ```
> foo
> |-foo
>   |- __init__.py
>   |- appincluder.py
>   |-apps
>     |-test
>       |- __init__.py
>       |- views.py
>       |- templates
>          |- test.jinja2
> ```

### foo/foo/**init**.py

```
config.include('foo.apps.test')
```

### foo/foo/appincluder.py

```
def appIncluder(config):
    app    = config.package
    prefix = app.prefix
    routes = app.routes

    for route,url in routes.items():
        config.add_route(route,prefix + url)

    config.scan(app)

    log.info('app: %s included' % app.__name__)
```

### foo/foo/apps/test/**init**.py

```
from foo.appincluder import appIncluder as includeme

prefix = '/test'

routes = {
    'test': '/home'
}
```

### foo/foo/apps/test/views.py

```
from pyramid.view import view_config


@view_config(route_name='test', renderer='templates/test.jinja2')
def test(request):
    return {}
```

**Info**: I prefer each app to come along with its config, hence the choice of putting the prefix in the app **init**.py file instead of specifying it in `config.include(app,prefix)`.